# Why is my onload not working in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I really need to use a onload and I don't understand why it's not working. I made a code snippet to test it out and yet again found that it didn't work. Is wordpress doing this? Or am I making a mistake? I found that events such as onclick and onchange are working.

```
function do_onload_event()
{
    return '<div id="loadevent" onload="do_show_event(event)"></div>' . '<script>
    function do_show_event(event)
    {
        console.log("on load event");
    }
    </script>';
}
add_shortcode('on_load_event','do_onload_event');
```

Comment: You can't onload to a div. Please Try with <body>:

Comment: Since wp has jquery you should use something like $(window).load(function() { // .... }); in your plugin / theme JS while enqueing in header. also, can you explain the shortcode context ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO - Calling onload from in-post shortcode could have many issues of timing or executions. Also, I am not sure that it is possible ot hook to `onLoad()` or `onready()` more than once so it would be more compatible..

Since we are dealing with wordpress, you could try another approach using jQuery:

```
function add_my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_init_script', 'MyScriptSource/etc', 'jquery', '1.0' ); // jQuery dependency
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_my_scripts' );
```

Then add another script that calls your method.

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    init();
});
```

You could of course try also for load event

```
jQuery(window).load(function($) {
   // your function
});
```

or ..

```
(function($) {
  // your function
})(jQuery);
```